# Does the React Context API replace the need for component props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-component, react-context

I've recently upgraded a React 15 project to use React 16.9. Specifically, I've completely replaced redux with the new Context API, pure functional components, and hooks.  With the Context API, we also gain the ability for nested child consumers to obtain the data without having to pass it using props all the way through. However, I noticed that I don't have any component props anywhere as everything is passed via provider/consumer context.

So my question is does the context API make component props obselete?

Comment: if you need to pass props one level deep, why would you use context API  for that ?

Answer (score 1):

I find people abuse `redux` and `context`. Btw, `redux` uses `context` internally.

To be honest, `prop` still should be your best friend in most of cases. Only when you want to avoid nested prop passing, you could then explore `context` where a provider is created as a parent, and then all deep down children can receive it as `props`.

`Prop` is still the way when children connect to the provider. The only difference is that these props are stored in a sort of "global" space now.

So in short, `context` doesn't replace `prop`, it still uses `prop`.

Answer (score 1):

You have already answered your question. Context API avoids I quote one from react docs :

**Context is primarily used when some data needs to be accessible by many components at different nesting levels. Apply it sparingly because it makes component reuse more difficult**

There is no other reason. If I want to reuse component or export it that depends context, user has no idea about it. Use cases like logged User, theme, or sone global state like work flow detail for the whole application etc, makes a good use case.